Question on Elastic Collisions and Energy conservation
I was given a true or false question in my test that says that in an elastic collision between two billiard balls, during a short period of time, kinetic energy is conserved. Many sources give the answer to be false, but I believe it is true. Can someone explain the correct answer?

In a direct collision in the center of mass frame the two balls come to a halt momentarily before heading back in opposite directions.

Thank you guys for all your answers.

This is not a good test question, hence your confusion. No macroscopic object can have an elastic collision, so you're being asked: In a situation where physics is violated: what physics happens? It's not answerable.
Per Jon Custer's comment: if we imagine the balls compress, then yes: in the CoM they slow down and reverse direction, so kinetic energy is not conserved.
Since the balls are deforming, their center of masses are still moving because they are no longer spheres, but there's that moment where they are motionless and loaded with potential energy.
OK, so you say, "No: it's a hypothetical, they don't compress, it's perfectly elastic!", which you can do, if you violate special relativity (see: Born Rigidity). If you include that, you should be able to convince yourself the collision is can't be symmetric around the point of maximum contact--you have to leave energy in vibration modes of the billiard balls, no matter how small, it's not zero.
So if you then say forget that: it's a Galiean collision of infinitely hard spheres, then the time it has zero KE (in the CoM) has measure zero, and you have to get a topologist to tell you if that counts.
The only way to have a truly elastic collision is if the two objects are coherent quantum states, like 2 protons. But then you still have to consider bremstrahlung. You can't win.
So, your confusion is warranted, and I reject the question on the following grounds: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8rxPrV-tn4

Consider an idealised 1D collision of two objects, and between them is an ideal spring. The word elastic referring to a collision, refers only to the fact that long after the collision, the sum total of kinetic energy (and identities) of the outgoing particles are exactly the same as the incoming particles.
With the spring, you can clearly see that during the interesting portion of the collision, kinetic energy had been transferred and stored as potential energy.
The question is worded specifically to ask students to consider this phenomenon and demonstrate an understanding that elastic collisions do not imply strict conservation of only kinetic energy throughout the collision process. The teacher's motivation, intent, and educational objectives are all superbly clear. It is just somewhat badly worded for students to understand.

It seems most important to note in a solution involving theoretical kinetic conservation that superfluous consideration is not voiced, thereby leaving the absolute representation of curvature at zero, because no attenuation is indicated the gradual assumption of clearly nothing.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
